# Unable to resume activity error after end video playback?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-videoview

I try to play videos in my app with intent But when end of video playback my app crashed. I use this method for call video player. So I call picture viewer with intent in this activity that append same problem.

```
  private void play_video() {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/nabege" + File.separator + "video"
        + File.separator + videoFileName);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);}
```

> 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): Process: com.example.nabege, PID: 15952 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.nabege/com.example.nabege.Show_subject_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946) 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2975) 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356) 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 09-26 15:48:23.862: E/AndroidRuntime(15952): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)

onpause() method :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
    stop_background_sound();
}
```

onresume method :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
    // Set the audio data source
    set_data_source_mpalyer();
    mController.setMediaPlayer(this);
    mController.setEnabled(true);
        }
```

:My activity codes are very long .If need to another methods add comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change onpause method like this and solved the problem:

```
if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
```